# ModuleNotFound: No module named 'pyttsx3'

Tags: visual-studio-code, modulenotfounderror, pyttsx3

I tried importing pyttsx3 module on my vscode but it kept on showing me error as ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3'.I had installed it on my terminal but still the error exists.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using virtual environment?
If yes then you have to do it in the virtual environment.